# Addition of UI elements in a cardboard application

Tags: android, google-cardboard, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

I want to make a 360 panorama viewer in Android studio.

The idea is to make it exactly like the existing googles street view application.

I want to know how to add a/some UI element inside the VR view so that if a user looks at it, the 360 picture would change to some other picture.

I know it is a long way to go but for now, if somebody could help me or direct me towards achieving it, it will really help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have already checked Treasure Hunt demo

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start is a demo app by Google called [TreasureHunt](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/get-started) (this is part of GoogleVR). Download the sample code compile and run you'll get a sense of what you need to do. TreasureHunt is also found on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.defcon.popo.treasurehunt).

Comment: thanks for your answer mate. Would you please let me know how to place a panorama image on the same demo. Some hint or some part of code will be really use full.